# Hana Delta merge (mergedog) event on fresh system

Tags: hana

After a fresh install of Hana SPS12 I get this event:

> Delta merge (mergedog) configuration ( ID 10 )
>
> Determines whether or not the 'active' parameter in the 'mergedog'
>   section of system configuration file(s) is 'yes'. mergedog is the
>   system process that periodically checks column tables to determine
>   whether or not a delta merge operation needs to be executed.

If this operation is so important why is it not a default setting? Why do I have to change this setting?

Answer (score 0):

This operation is important. Therefore the default setting for Mergedog active is yes. The system checks the setting and alerts like reported. See alert message above. 
This check should not be done for services without own persistence like dpserver. There was a useless check for dpserver which caused that wrong alert.
You may ignore the alert for now and change the setting. Finally it will go away after next upgrade.